# Sorting sorted string descending

Tags: java

I want this string to be sorted descending way regarded to repeated characters.

For example I have this string:  "aabbbc" or "ddfssskkk".

The desired string is: "bbbaac" or "ssskkkddf".

Comment: And what have you tried doing?

Comment: As-is the question is likely to be closed. Please include at least *some* effort. It seems relatively straight-forward; break it up into groups, sort those groups by two criteria: number of characters first, and the character itself if the group lengths are equal.

Comment: @DaveNewton how can I break it into groups?what method I need to use in Arrays class or char[]?

Comment: You just need to iterate characters and count them; I'd consider looking through a few APIs (e.g., `java.lang.String`) and see if anything strikes your fancy. If you have to handle something like `"aabbaaacccc"` you'd need to decide what that means, though.

Comment: Pro tips for posting, hope they are useful. There's no need to add "thanks in advance" to everything, this tends to get trimmed out anyway (causes work). Ditto "please help me", which is sometimes read as a form of  begging. For some of your questions where you've received heavy downvoting, they can sometimes feel too broad or, as here, unresearched. Ask yourself whether you've demonstrated effort for every question, and that will help improve the reception you get.

Answer (score 1):

I wont give you a full answer but hopefully make it much easier for you :)

```
import java.util.Arrays;

class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] letterFrequency = new int['z' -'a']; //create an array of length 26 representing all lowercase letters
    String s = "aabbbc";

    for(int i = 0; i < s.length();i++) {
      letterFrequency[s.charAt(i) -'a'] += 1; //adds 1 to the corresponding position in letterFrequency for each character in the string
    }

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(letterFrequency));
  }
}
```

**Output:**

```
[2, 3, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

So use the knowledge that there are 3 `b`'s 2 `a`'s and 1 `c` from the array `letterFrequency` to sort your string as you desire :)

Answer (score 0):

This does what you need, there is a lot of string manipulations

```
  private static String sortDuplicates(String in) {

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(in);
    char[] chars = in.toCharArray();
    List<Integer> indexes = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
      if (i < chars.length - 1 && chars[i] != chars[i + 1]) {

        if (count == 0) {
          sb.append(chars[i]);
          indexes.add(i);
        } else {
          count = 0;
        }
      } else {
        count++;
      }
    }

    for (Object a : indexes.toArray()) {
      sb.deleteCharAt((Integer) a);
    }

    char[] a = sb.toString().substring(0, sb.length() - indexes.size()).toCharArray();
    Arrays.sort(a);
    StringBuilder d = new StringBuilder(new String(a)).reverse();

    return d.toString() + sb.substring(sb.length() - indexes.size());
  }
```